# Extruding Height in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: modelbuilder, kml, arcgis-pro

I am trying to create a ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro to convert KML files to Multipatch. The steps:

1. KML to Layer tool
2. I select the layer and in the Appearance contextual tabs, I will extrude the height
3. Layer 3D to Feature Class tool

I have the conversion tools which i can add into the model, but I cannot find a tool to extrude the layer height, thus I cannot create a model to automate the process. 
Is there a way where I can extrude the height using tool in ModelBuilder, so the when I convert to Multipatch, it will contain the height as well?

Comment: Try: manually perform the workflow, once the layer looks how you want it, create a LYRX file and save it to disk. Then build your model with Apply Symbology from Layer tool in between the 2 tools. Alternatively look at using a task, while it wont completely automate a 1 -click solution, you can have it launch tools and believe can have it aid in performing the symbolization.

Comment: @KHibma I think that would suffice as an answer if you have time to post it.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @KHibma:

> Try: manually perform the workflow, once the layer looks how you want
>   it, create a LYRX file and save it to disk. Then build your model with
>   Apply Symbology from Layer tool in between the 2 tools. Alternatively
>   look at using a task, while it wont completely automate a 1 -click
>   solution, you can have it launch tools and believe can have it aid in
>   performing the symbolization.